# Simon Says: "Make me a pretty game"

Tags: c#, wpf, community-challenge, async-await, simon-says

> ***In Memoriam***
>
> *Ralph H. Baer, co-inventor of the original "Simon" game, [died Saturday December 6<sup>th</sup> 2014, at 92](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/12/08/business/ralph-h-baer-dies-inventor-of-odyssey-first-system-for-home-video-games.html?_r=0). With his passing, this friendly little challenge inadvertently became a memorial to the father of video game consoles. Rest in peace Mr. Baer, you have changed our lives forever.*

---

I finally got my [*Simon Says*](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3785/23788) implementation to work as I intended it to. That's great, but now I'm left with a mess and I'm not sure where to start cleaning up (full code on [GitHub](https://github.com/retailcoder/SimonSays/tree/master/SimonSays)).

Per the specs, there was going to be 4 buttons. So I created an `enum` and called it `SimonButton`:

```
public enum SimonButton
{
    Green,
    Red,
    Blue,
    Yellow
}
```

I created a `SimonSaysRound` class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, to bind with the UI, mostly to provide the player's score.

```
public class SimonSaysRound : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private const int PointsForGoodMatch = 5;

    private readonly SimonButton[] _sequence;
    private int _matches;
    private int _score;

    public SimonSaysRound(IEnumerable<SimonButton> sequence, int score)
    {
        _sequence = sequence.ToArray();
        _score = score;
        _matches = 0;
    }

    public event EventHandler<SimonSaysScoreEventArgs> RoundCompleted;
    public void OnRoundCompleted()
    {
        var handler = RoundCompleted;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var result = _matches == _sequence.Length;
            RoundCompleted(this, new SimonSaysScoreEventArgs(result, Score));
        }
    }

    public void Play(SimonButton button)
    {
        var success = _sequence[_matches] == button;
        if (success)
        {
            Score += PointsForGoodMatch;
            _matches++;
        }

        if (!success || _matches == _sequence.Length)
        {
            OnRoundCompleted();
        }
    }

    public int Round
    {
        get { return _sequence.Length; }
    }

    public int Score
    {
        get { return _score; }
        private set
        {
            if (value == _score) return;
            _score = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int Length { get { return _sequence.Length; } }
    public IEnumerable<SimonButton> Sequence { get { return _sequence; } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I don't normally implement my `INotifyPropertyChanged` like this - ReSharper suggested something, and I wanted to see what it did.. and I don't dislike it.

When the application starts, the main window is displayed, and an animation reveals a "Start" button:

[image: Start!]

When the button is clicked, the message bar collapses, and a button flashes by quickly animating a radial gradient's offset value (with accompanying sound effects):

[image: Blue quadrant lit]

When the player enters the correct sequence, the middle bar expands reveals a "round completed" message that shows the player their score; game resumes when the player clicks /collapses the message:

[image: Round 1 completed! Ready?]

The "Game Over" screen displays the player's score, and the number of completed rounds; clicking the message closes the window, and then the program ends:

[image: Oops! 6 rounds completed. Your score: 115]

The XAML/UI is reviewable [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/71904/23788); this post is about the actual application code:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private readonly MainWindow _mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    private SimonSaysRound _currentRound;

    private readonly IDictionary<SimonButton, string> _sounds;

    private readonly int _seed;

    public App()
    {
        _seed = new Random().Next();

        var folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(GetType().Assembly.Location);
        _sounds = Enum.GetValues(typeof (SimonButton))
                      .Cast<SimonButton>()
                      .ToDictionary(button => button,
                                    button => Path.Combine(folder ?? string.Empty, "Resources", button + ".wav"));
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        _mainWindow.SimonButtonClicked += OnSimonButtonClick;
        _mainWindow.PlayNextRound += _mainWindow_PlayNextRound;
        _mainWindow.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void _mainWindow_PlayNextRound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PlayNextRound();
    }

    private void PlayNextRound()
    {
        var sequenceLength = 1;
        var score = 0;
        if (_currentRound != null)
        {
            sequenceLength = _currentRound.Length + 1;
            score = _currentRound.Score;
        }

        _currentRound = new SimonSaysRound(GenerateSequence(sequenceLength), score);
        _currentRound.RoundCompleted += _currentRound_RoundCompleted;
        _mainWindow.DataContext = _currentRound;
        _mainWindow.DataContext = _currentRound;
        PlaySequence();
    }

    private IEnumerable<SimonButton> GenerateSequence(int length)
    {
        var random = new Random(_seed);
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            yield return (SimonButton)random.Next(Enum.GetValues(typeof(SimonButton)).GetLength(0));
        }
    }

    private void _currentRound_RoundCompleted(object sender, SimonSaysRoundCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Success)
        {
            _mainWindow.OnRoundSuccessful();
        }
        else
        {
            _mainWindow.OnGameOver();
        }
    }

    private async Task PlaySequence()
    {
        foreach (var button in _currentRound.Sequence)
        {
            await OnSimonButtonClickAsync(null, new SimonButtonEventArgs(button));
            Thread.Sleep(300);
        }
    }

    private void OnSimonButtonClick(object sender, SimonButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        OnSimonButtonClickAsync(sender, e);
    }

    private async Task OnSimonButtonClickAsync(object sender, SimonButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var player = new SoundPlayer(_sounds[e.Button]))
        {
            player.Play();
        }

        if (sender != null)
        {
            _currentRound.Play(e.Button);
        }

        await _mainWindow.HighlightSimonButton(e.Button);
    }
}
```

And the code-behind for the main window:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly IDictionary<SimonButton, Border> _buttons;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _buttons = new Dictionary<SimonButton, Border>
            {
                { SimonButton.Green, Green },
                { SimonButton.Red, Red },
                { SimonButton.Yellow, Yellow },
                { SimonButton.Blue, Blue }
            };

        RegisterName(MessageBar.Name, MessageBar);
        foreach (var button in _buttons)
        {
            RegisterName(button.Value.Name, button.Value);
        }

        DisableButtons();

        MouseDown += MainWindow_MouseDown;
        Activated += MainWindow_Activated;
    }

    private async void MainWindow_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GameScoreLabel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        GameButton.Text = "Start!";

        await AnimateMessageBand(36);
        Activated -= MainWindow_Activated;

        GameButton.MouseDown += GameButtonStartGame;
    }

    private void MainWindow_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
        {
            DragMove();
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<SimonButtonEventArgs> SimonButtonClicked;
    public async Task OnSimonButtonClicked(SimonButton button)
    {
        var handler = SimonButtonClicked;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler.Invoke(this, new SimonButtonEventArgs(button));
        }
    }

    public async Task OnGameOver()
    {
        GameButton.Text = string.Format("Oops! {0} rounds completed.", ((SimonSaysRound)DataContext).Round - 1);
        GameScoreLabel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        await AnimateMessageBand(56);

        DisableButtons();

        GameButton.MouseDown += GameButtonEndGame;
    }

    private void DisableButtons()
    {
        Green.MouseDown -= Green_MouseDown;
        Red.MouseDown -= Red_MouseDown;
        Yellow.MouseDown -= Yellow_MouseDown;
        Blue.MouseDown -= Blue_MouseDown;
    }

    public void EnableButtons()
    {
        Green.MouseDown += Green_MouseDown;
        Red.MouseDown += Red_MouseDown;
        Yellow.MouseDown += Yellow_MouseDown;
        Blue.MouseDown += Blue_MouseDown;
    }

    public async Task OnRoundSuccessful()
    {
        DisableButtons();
        GameButton.Text = string.Format("Round {0} completed! Ready?", ((SimonSaysRound)DataContext).Round);
        GameScoreLabel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        await AnimateMessageBand(56);
        GameButton.MouseDown += GameButtonNextRound;
    }

    private async Task AnimateMessageBand(double height)
    {
        var animation = new DoubleAnimation(height, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200)));

        Storyboard.SetTargetName(animation, MessageBar.Name);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("Height"));

        var story = new Storyboard();
        story.Children.Add(animation);
        await story.BeginAsync(MessageBar);

        story.Remove();
    }

    public async Task HighlightSimonButton(SimonButton button)
    {
        var border = _buttons[button];
        var animation = new DoubleAnimation(0, 0.75, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)));

        Storyboard.SetTargetName(animation, button.ToString());
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("Background.GradientStops[1].Offset"));

        var story = new Storyboard();
        story.Children.Add(animation);
        await story.BeginAsync(border);

        story.Remove();
    }

    private void Blue_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        OnSimonButtonClicked(SimonButton.Blue);
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void Yellow_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        OnSimonButtonClicked(SimonButton.Yellow);
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void Green_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        OnSimonButtonClicked(SimonButton.Green);
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void Red_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        OnSimonButtonClicked(SimonButton.Red);
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private async void GameButtonStartGame(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        await AnimateMessageBand(0);
        e.Handled = true;

        GameButton.MouseDown -= GameButtonStartGame;

        var handler = PlayNextRound;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        EnableButtons();
    }

    public event EventHandler PlayNextRound;
    private async void GameButtonNextRound(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        await AnimateMessageBand(0);
        e.Handled = true;

        var handler = PlayNextRound;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        GameButton.MouseDown -= GameButtonNextRound;
        EnableButtons();
    }

    private void GameButtonEndGame(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

I'm using this extension method I borrowed on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14695474/1188513) (had to tweak it a little), to make `Storyboard` animations awaitable and avoid having all animations running simultaneously:

```
public static class StoryboardExtensions
{
    public static Task BeginAsync(this Storyboard storyboard, FrameworkElement containingObject)
    {
        var source = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        if (storyboard == null)
            source.SetException(new ArgumentNullException());
        else
        {
            EventHandler onComplete = null;
            onComplete = (sender, args) =>
            {
                storyboard.Completed -= onComplete;
                source.SetResult(true);
            };
            storyboard.Completed += onComplete;
            containingObject.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => storyboard.Begin(containingObject));
        }
        return source.Task;
    }
}
```

Comment: One small hint regarding your commits: A commit message "fixed" is really not that helpful. Try to be more descriptive in your commit messages even if you're developing by yourself.

Comment: @germi You're right (but [there's worse ;)](https://github.com/ncase/polygons/commits/gh-pages?page=1))

Comment: http://xkcd.com/1296/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Well, first questions is: why don't you use MVVM? Contents of your `App` class look like something that should be implemented on model/view model level.
2. This looks like a lot of copy-pasting

   ```
   private void Blue_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   {
       OnSimonButtonClicked(SimonButton.Blue);
       e.Handled = true;
   }

   private void Yellow_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   {
       OnSimonButtonClicked(SimonButton.Yellow);
       e.Handled = true;
   }

   ....
   ```

You should use single event handler for your buttons. For example, you can set button type to `FrameworkElement.Tag` in XAML, and access it as `((FrameworkElement)sender).Tag` in code behind. You can also refactor those into commands, if you were to use bindings instead of events.

3. I don't like your `EnableButtons` and `DisableButtons` methods, they feel wrong. I would bind `IsEnabled` property of your buttons to some bool dependency property (or viewmodel property), and set it to true/false instead. And I would then check this property in the event handler.
4. You should use some static method to do this:

   ```
   var handler = myEvent;
   if (handler != null)
   {
       handler(this, myArgs);
   }
   ```
5. I don't know the whole story, but I don't quite understand why do you need to await for animations. It only makes your code more complex. Also, I think that managing and defining storyboards is a lot easier in XAML than in code-behind, but, it might be a matter of taste.

Answer (score 15):

- Magic numbers, you have at least one of them in class `App`: `private async Task PlaySequence()` you should extract this to either a constant or better to a property, so that the speed, aka less sleep, can be adjusted.
- I don't see the point of the `_seed` variable. Yeah, I know why you use it, but it just forces you, each time the `GenerateSequence()` method is called, to recreate the `IEnumerable<SimonButton>`. Consider to append the "new"  item for the sequence to the end of the sequence.
- each time calling `Enum.GetValues(typeof(SimonButton)).GetLength(0)` at creating the random is not necessary either. Extract it to a variable and reuse it, it won't change ;-)
- assigning the `DataContext` two times might be a copy & paste error
- The whole `GenerateSequence()` method should live in the `SimonSaysRound` class. You wouldn't need to access `Score` and `Length` properties.
- `SimonSaysRound` could also get rid of the `SimonButton[]` because it could use an `IEnumerable<>` instead. This will also result in `Length` property getting obsolete.

**Refactoring** the `SimonSaysRound` class by implementing the points above will lead to

```
public class SimonSaysRound : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private const int PointsForGoodMatch = 5;
    private readonly int _buttonCount = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SimonButton)).GetLength(0);

    private IEnumerable<SimonButton> _sequence = Enumerable.Empty<SimonButton>();
    private IEnumerator<SimonButton> _enumerator;

    private int _matches=0;
    private int _score=0;
    private int _currentlength = 0;

    private Random _random = new Random();

    /// <summary>
    /// Use this method, to start a new game.
    /// </summary>
    public void Reset()
    {
        _matches = 0;
        _score = 0;
        _currentlength = 0;
        _sequence = Enumerable.Empty<SimonButton>();
    }

    public event EventHandler<SimonSaysScoreEventArgs> RoundCompleted;
    public void OnRoundCompleted()
    {
        var handler = RoundCompleted;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var result = _matches == _currentlength;
            RoundCompleted(this, new SimonSaysScoreEventArgs(result, Score));
        }
    }

    public void Play(SimonButton button)
    {
        _enumerator.MoveNext();
        var success = _enumerator.Current == button;
        if (success)
        {
            Score += PointsForGoodMatch;
            _matches++;
        }

        if (!success || _matches == _currentlength)
        {
            OnRoundCompleted();
        }
    }

    public int Round
    {
        get { return _currentlength; }
    }

    public int Score
    {
        get { return _score; }
        private set
        {
            if (value == _score) return;
            _score = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<SimonButton> Sequence { get { return _sequence; } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public void PlayNextRound()
    {
        _matches = 0;
        _currentlength += 1;
        _sequence = _sequence.Concat(GenerateNextSequenceItem());
        _enumerator = _sequence.GetEnumerator();

    }

    private IEnumerable<SimonButton> GenerateNextSequenceItem()
    {
        yield return (SimonButton)_random.Next(_buttonCount);
    }      
}
```

and on the calling side

```
private void PlayNextRound()
{
    if (_currentRound == null)
    {
        _currentRound = new SimonSaysRound();
    }
    _currentRound.PlayNextRound();
    _currentRound.RoundCompleted += _currentRound_RoundCompleted;

    _mainWindow.DataContext = _currentRound;

    PlaySequence();
}
```

You should consider to initialize the `_currentRound` on class level making the null check obsolete.

- combining the start of a game and the start of the next round by raising the same event without to distinguish between them by using different event arguments, is IMHO not very good.
- you have duplicate code in the `GameButtonStartGame()` and `GameButtonNextRound()` methods. Either remove one of the methods and change the eventhandler or better extract the code to a separate method which is called form both handlers.

Answer (score 6):

The naming is inconsistent with the rest of the code in the borrowed extension method:

> ```
>     EventHandler onComplete = null;
>     onComplete = (sender, args) =>
>     {
>         storyboard.Completed -= onComplete;
>         source.SetResult(true);
>     };
>     storyboard.Completed += onComplete;
>     containingObject.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => storyboard.Begin(containingObject));
> ```

`OnSimonButtonClicked` and every single `OnEventName` method you've ever written calls the handler `handler`:

> ```
>     var handler = SimonButtonClicked;
>     if (handler != null)
>     {
>         handler.Invoke(this, new SimonButtonEventArgs(button));
>     }
> ```

This would be more consistent then - notice the `= null` assignment is redundant and has been removed:

```
    EventHandler handler;
    handler = (sender, args) =>
    {
        storyboard.Completed -= handler;
        source.SetResult(true);
    };
    storyboard.Completed += handler;
    containingObject.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => storyboard.Begin(containingObject));
```